# Can we pass a string to method expecting vector parameter?

Tags: java, vector

I have a method to send email whose signature is

```
sendemail(Vector addr, String subject, String body)
```

zvector addr contains email address to which the email has to be sent.

If we have multiple, separated email addresses then we add each to
Vector and pass it. But now I want to send the email to only 1 address.

> So can I pass the String email address directly to the method or need
>   to add single string also to the Vector?

Comment: BTW: [Vector is seldom appropiate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated). And Java classes are case sensitive (vector => Vector, string => String)

Comment: sorry while writing here typing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to instantiate a new `vector<String>` and add the `String` to it.

Another solution would be to overload the function with a different signature:

```
sendemail(Vector<String> addr, String subject, String body) {
  ..
}

sendemail(String addr, String subject, String body) {
  Vector<String> vaddr = new Vector<String>();
  vaddr.add(addr);
  sendemail(vaddr, subject, body);
}
```

So that a new `Vector` is still instantiated but at least you can use which one signature you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a one-element `Vector`. Here's a method to create a one-item Vector:

```
public <T> Vector<T> singletonVector(T item) {
    Vector<T> v = new Vector<T>(1);
    v.add(item);
    return v;
}
```

If you change your `sendemail` method to take a `java.util.List` instead, you could use the `Collections.singletonList` method to create your one-item `List`. And since `Vector` implements `List`, you won't have to change any existing code that calls `sendemail`.

```
sendemail(Collections.singletonList(emailAddress), mySubject, myBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the single string to the vector.

What you can do if you can modify sendemail is to define it as:

```
public void sendemail(String subject, String body, String ... addr)
```

and then you don't need to construct a vector, you just pass the addresses.

Comment: sendemail email is an existing functionality and is used to send email in  multiple scenarios. So i dont think i can change the signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
sendemail(String...addr, String subject, String body)
{

    //addr.length(): The number of email address
    //addr[0]: 1st email adrdess 
    //addr[1]: 2nd email adrdess 
    .
    .
    .
    //addr[addr.length-1]: last email adrdess 

}
```

I recommend you write like this:

```
sendemail(String...addr)
{

    subject=addr[addr.lentgh-2];
    body=addr[addr.lentgh-1];
    addr[0]..addr[addr.length-3]: email addresses.

}
```